# Rolling average cost

Tags: python, pandas

I have the `dataframe`;

```
df_exa = pd.DataFrame([['B', 20, 123], ['B', 14, 125], ['S', 15, 123],
                   ['B', 14, 122.5], ['S', 1,124], ['B', 4, 128]],
                  columns=['Buy_Sell', 'quantity', 'price'],
                  index=['Basket1', 'Basket2', 'Basket3', 'Basket4',
                         'Basket5', 'Basket6'])
```

I am looking to calculated the rolling cumulated cost (so taking in account only the B (for Buys))
And my result should look like the following :

```
df_exa_avg_cost = pd.DataFrame([['B', 20, 123, 123], ['B', 14, 125,123.8235], ['S', 15, 123, 123.5714],
                   ['B', 14, 122.5,123.3333], ['S', 1,124, 123.3333], ['B', 4, 128, 123.6119]],
                  columns=['Buy_Sell', 'quantity', 'price','avg_cost'],
                  index=['Basket1', 'Basket2', 'Basket3', 'Basket4',
                         'Basket5', 'Basket6'])
```

I know how to populate the new column `avg_cost` with a `for loop`, but i am trying to use something more efficient as the number of basket transactions can grow significantly.
Would anyone know how to achieve this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want avg_price for 'B's only that carries over for 'S' you can do

```
buys = (df_exa['Buy_Sell'] == 'B')
df_exa.loc[buys, 'avg_cost'] = ((df_exa.loc[buys, 'quantity']*df_exa.loc[buys,'price']).cumsum()/df_exa.loc[buys,'quantity'].cumsum())
df_exa.fillna(method = 'ffill')
```

to give you

```
        Buy_Sell    quantity    price   avg_cost
Basket1 B           20          123.0   123.000000
Basket2 B           14          125.0   123.823529
Basket3 S           15          123.0   123.823529
Basket4 B           14          122.5   123.437500
Basket5 S           1           124.0   123.437500
Basket6 B           4           128.0   123.788462
```

Comment: when it is a sell row, we keep the avg cost unchanged, since selling does not impact the cost of entry actually.

Comment: got it. modified the answer for posterity

Answer (score 1):

You stated you want the cumulative average cost for just B which is done via:

```
df_exa['total'] = df_exa['quantity']*df_exa['price']

df_buy_ex = df_exa[df_exa['Buy_Sell'] == 'B'].copy()

df_buy_ex['t_cumsum'] = df_buy_ex['total'].cumsum()
df_buy_ex['q_cumsum'] = df_buy_ex['quantity'].cumsum()
df_buy_ex['cum_avg_p'] = df_buy_ex['t_cumsum']/df_buy_ex['q_cumsum']
df_exa_avg = df_exa.merge(df_buy_ex['cum_avg_p'], how='left',left_index=True,right_index=True)
df_exa_avg.ffill(inplace=True)

df_exa_avg[['Buy_Sell','quantity','price','cum_avg_p']]
```

This actually gives you the following:

[image]

Whilst your desired outcome values are actually more inlined with taking the cumulative average cost for both B and S:

```
df_exa['total'] = df_exa['quantity']*df_exa['price']
df_exa['t_cumsum'] = df_exa['total'].cumsum()
df_exa['q_cumsum'] = df_exa['quantity'].cumsum()
df_exa['cum_avg_p'] = df_exa['t_cumsum']/df_exa['q_cumsum']

df_exa[['Buy_Sell','quantity','price','cum_avg_p']]
```

Gives output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Jojo, you were super fast and so much care in your response. I gave the check to Piter because his solution is much shorter.  Just wanted to make sure you are ok with that. THANK YOU very much